# List going back to 0 after new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this class:

```
public class Observador : iObservador
{
    private List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>();
    public void DeSubscribirse(Form form)
    {
        Forms.Remove(form);
    }

    public void Limpiar()
    {
        Forms.Clear();
    }

    public void Subscribirse(Form form)
    {
        Forms.Add(form);
    }

    public List<Form> DevolverSubscriptos()
    {
        return this.Forms;
    }
}
```

Which is used on a base form I have like this:

```
public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public EE.Observador Watcher = new Observador();

    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

    }
}
```

Which I use for the rest of my forms to be inherited from.

My idea is to have in all the forms a reference to the object Watcher from every place, with it having a reference for every form which is subscribed to it. So I can do for example, from `FormB` know that `FormA` is already subscribed with the method `DevolverSubscriptos()` (this means return subscribers)  and access it to make it visible again after closing `FormB`.

The problem is that when I start `FormB` the list of Watcher with the whole forms is set back to 0.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

```
public partial class AdminUIGI : FormBase.FormBase
```

That's how I reference it.

Comment: Actually, that is a Design smell in my nose. You'll end up with highly coupled Forms. What _problem_ are you trying to solve using this?

Comment: i was trying to reproduce an observer pattern

Comment: Yes, as discussed in comments to decPL's answer, I think looking into "MVC with winforms" will spare you some headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you're using an instance field. Each form is a separate instance, hence each has it's own copy of the `EE.Observador`.

So a quick and dirty fix would be to make this field `static`, i.e. shared by all instances of the given class. And if you want to improve, you might then consider reading about the Singleton pattern (mainly because you'll see it used a lot - but read on :) ), then read why using Singleton as a global variable is in fact an anti-pattern and move on to reading about dependency injection and IoC - which is how (in vacuum at least) your code should probably end up. (Note: for a quick and dirty solution `static` field is all you need).

Comment: And how can i make the forms that inherit from Base to use the same Watcher?

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry - premature enter key :P

Comment: Haha no problem @decPL i think i'm starting with the static as you say and then go with that. Should i make the list from `EE.Observador` as static or the definition on `FormBase`?

Comment: You can add "MVC" and "MVVM" to the list of evolution steps :D

Comment: @MatiasM That is no excuse. You _can_ do MVC with winforms. (Do not mix up with "ASP.Net MVC". It's just a pattern name.)

Comment: @Fildor really? I had no idea. I'm used to web not to winforms. I will investigate

Comment: @MatiasM Yes, it's a little tricky but absolutely worth looking into. Especially with the utilities like IoC frameworks you have today, I'd always prefer designing for MVC with winforms than not to.

Answer (score 0):

```
@decPL I made it work with the singleton pattern doing this `    public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    public static EE.Observador watcher = new Observador();
    private Usuario userInstance = null;`
```